# Selecting output directory changes database file path

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, pdf, path

I've created an application with C# + SQLite library.
There is a function to print out contracts, it works fine with printer, but when I choose a PDF writer for printer it creates a new empty db file at the output pdf's directory (for example: C:\Documents...). Of course the program can't read anything from database for creating the pdf and drops exception for missing tables.

It just happens only on my laptop. It works fine with my PC.

My connection string:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
...
SQLiteConnection con;
con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + "\\db1.db3; Version=3;
                            Pooling=True; Max Pool Size=100");
```

The path string is defined in the form's constructor, so it must points to my application's directory always.

If I choose the software's folder it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` gets currently active directory and this could be different from your app dir.
You'd better use:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```